# need custom formatting of input type=number in HTML5

Tags: html

I need to use type="number" so that number keyboard appears. Also the number should take decimal. The thousand separator will be . and decimal separator will be comma. Can anybody helps me out?

Answer (score 0):

The formatting of the keyboard will be up to the keyboard settings of the user's device.